# Integrating payment gateway with volusion

Tags: c#, payment-gateway

I am working for a payment gateway company. They want me to integrate their payment gateway with volusion ecommerce. I am not able to find any documents on integrating a gateway for a developer. Any directions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? [Where Do I Find Information on the Volusion API?](http://support.volusion.com/article/where-do-i-find-information-volusion-api)

Comment: but I am unable to find any details about developing our gateway according to their expectations to receive credit card info

Comment: anyways,Stackoverflow encourages accepting answers irrespective of whether it really answers the question or not. So Lucky you, here's your answer ticked :)